# how to effectively segregate URLs, IP Addresses, Subnets, FQDNs

Tags: shell

I have a list of following put in a single file.

1. URLs like www.yahoo.com or yahoo.co.in
2. Full Urls like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
3. Ip Addresses like 172.9.8.1, etc
4. Subnets like 172.16.4.1/24, etc
   and
5. Some regular expressions like *.yahoo.com, etc

I need to segregate these and put these in seperate files.

I created a c++ program to do this, but client wants this to be done via shell script :(

Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: in the list of IP Addresses, there are IPV6 addresses also.

Comment: This appears to be a matter of crafting the appropriate regular expressions. Instead of reinventing some wheels, I'd start with [Regexp::Common](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Common)

Comment: You need to specify what each value looks like before anyone can help.